# Windows 7 - Acer Aspire M5811

Tags: windows-7, performance

I have a problem with my Windows 7 Desktop PC. Today I used it normally and it turned off normally to, but the next time I tried to turn it on, it became extremely slow. It's normal until I need to enter my password, but after that it's like it has a 40 years old processor inside, it just doesn't do anything!
 Before it took ~3 mins to get everything loaded (Skype, Steam, the widgets) and now it can't even load the widgets (when it can, it takes 30 mins to do so), which makes the PC practically unusable.
 It even crashes when loading the start menu... And when I finally got Task Manager to open, it showed only ~1% of CPU usage, which, I would guess, it's strange since it's trying to open a program right? 
 This started yesterday and I couldn't even shut the computer down. Today, when trying to turn it on it showed a Bluescreen but it was so quick I couldn't see the error, and it restarted (it's still impossible slow) but, since then, never showed the Bluescreen or the error report/message again.
 I don´t know what to do since I can't do anything in that PC to try to solve it because it just doesn't load anything.
 I'm writing this on another computer because I can't do it the my main PC.
 I would be very grateful if anyone could help!

Thanks,

Comment: Start by resetting the bios to the default settings and remove all the unnecessary expansion cards.